# Replacing Pattern Matches in a String

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
String output = "";
pattern = Pattern.compile(">Part\s.");
matcher = pattern.matcher(docToProcess);
while (matcher.find()) {
      match = matcher.group();
}
```

I'm trying to use the above code to find the pattern `>Part\s.` inside `docToProcess` (Which is a string of a large xml document) and then what I want to do is replace the content that matches the pattern with `<ref></ref>`

Any ideas how I can make the `output` variable equal to `docToProcess` except with the replacements as indicated above?

**EDIT: I need to use the matcher somehow when replacing. I can't just use `replaceAll()`**

Comment: String.replaceAll() won't do it?? just curious

Comment: If already using the full `Matcher` API, it is `matcher.appendReplacement` and `matcher.appendTail` after the loop.

Comment: I've tried `replaceAll()` and `replace()` but each of them had problems. If you could show me some code of how you would do it? Perhaps I just tried the wrong things... I would paste what I did but I changed it and don't have it anymore.

Comment: @ThreaT "had problems" isn't very descriptive. Always describe what the problem was if you want help with it. `replaceAll` was made for exactly what you're doing, you'd need a fairly compelling reason to go for a more complicated approach.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yeah you're on the right track, if you could make an answer using that then I'd mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @Thor84no: I knew that someone would say this. No I know what I'm saying, taking that `replaceAll()` path isn't going to help with what I'm trying to do. It's complicated, I'm oversimplifying the problem I'm having big time and that's why you're saying that. `replaceAll()` doesn't really allow you to make references to the found matches unless you use `$1` which is **very** limited and doesn't work in a coder-friendly way. I need to be able to use variables and pass them around to methods without passing around an actual `"$1"` as understood by external methods.

Comment: @ThreaT "I knew someone would say this.[...] I'm oversimplifying the problem I'm having big time". Have you considered that maybe you should include constraint, limitations, and why some more obvious approaches won't work for you if you want a useful and helpful answer? Simplifying is great, oversimplifying makes the people trying to help you stumble around in the dark. There is no indication in anything you've written so far that shows any sign that what you're doing could be "too complicated" for `replaceAll` other than your assertion that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
String docToProcess = "... your xml here ...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(">Part\\s.");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(docToProcess);
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) matcher.appendReplacement(output, "<ref></ref>");
matcher.appendTail(output);
```

Unfortunately, you can't use the `StringBuilder` due to historical constraints on the Java API.

Comment: Aw!! Just added the same thing to my answer. +1 to the answer anyways :)

Comment: @RohitJain I don't think OP wanted to escape the dot. I'll remove it.

Comment: @Marko.. Yeah it is not clear from the question, so I can't back my comment. Better to keep the original :)

Comment: @Downvoter.. Can't understand, Why a Downvote on THIS answer??

Comment: @RohitJain It's OP, he wanted to remove his upvote, but downvoted instead (by mistake, I guess).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. It takes a `Regex` as first parameter: -

```
String output = docToProcess.replaceAll(">Part\\s\\.", "<ref></ref>");
```

Note that, `dot (.)` is a special meta-character in `regex`, which matches everything, and not just a `dot(.)`. So, you need to escape it, unless you really wanted to match any character after `>Part\\s`. And you need to add 2 backslashes to escape in Java.

---

If you want to use `Matcher` class, the you can use [Matcher.appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) method: -

```
 String docToProcess = "XYZ>Part .asdf";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(">Part\\s\\.");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(docToProcess);
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 while (m.find()) {
     m.appendReplacement(sb, "<ref></ref>");
 }
 m.appendTail(sb);
 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
"XYZ<ref></ref>asdf"
```

Comment: Lol I want to mark yours and Marko's answer right because he got it first but yours worked really well. Not sure what to do

Comment: @ThreaT.. Ah! never get confused while marking any answer. Just mark the best one. And if two are same, just mark the one which you feel got first. So, certainly mark **Marko's answer**. No problem :) What you can do is, add an upvote as a complement to the answer that you didn't marked accepted. ;)

Comment: @ThreaT I did write my answer because you specifically asked me to :) Otherwise I would've stayed with the comment.

Comment: Tell you what. I'm gonna vote yours up and give Marko the right answer. Yours will have more votes than his.

Comment: @ThreaT You could have just **UN**-upvoted my answer. Now you've actually **down** voted it, which is not really a customary thing to do here for an answer that you don't want to punish.

Comment: @ThreaT.. Did you really un-upvoted and downvoted Marko's answer?? If yes, please revert your vote. Downvoting an answer means it was not useful. But you just marked it as useful. So you are contradicting yourself by doing both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
docToProcess.replaceAll(">Part\\s[.]", "<ref></ref>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String output = docToProcess.replaceAll(">Part\\s\\.", "<ref></ref>");
```